# How to grab intent on initial launch of application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I currently have a xamarin application. I redirect the client based on what intent is received. It works perfectly when the app in in the background or foreground.

The issue I currently have is the redirect bit of code doesn't trigger when the app is removed from the system tray.

```
protected async override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    var data = intent.Data; // this returns testurl.com/?firstname=john&lastname=doe

    App.Firstname= intent.GetStringExtra("firstname");           
    App.Lastname= intent.GetStringExtra("lastname");
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
}
```

May I ask how do I keep my intents on app launch? I am unsure how to even debug this, when the app is removed from the system tray, visual studio stops running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bundle that you get from your MainActivity OnCreate method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Intent.Data;
    if (uri != null)
    {
        App.Firstname = uri.GetQueryParameter("firstname");
        App.Lastname = uri.GetQueryParameter("lastname");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful suggestion! The only question I have left is what the parameter name will be. I also grab intent date from the incoming url. `var urlString = intent?.DataString;`

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, but, you can get the query parameters using the following code:

`Android.Net.Uri uri = Intent.Data;`
`if (uri != null)`
`{`
`string x = uri.GetQueryParameter("firstname");`
`string y = uri.GetQueryParameter("lastname");`
`}`

Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it was helpful.

Comment: any thoughts on how to do the exact same for iOS